# Why didn't Dumbledore simply cut off his hand and make a new one?

Tags: harry-potter

Firstly, in *the Deathly Hallows* when Harry was re-living Snape's memories from the Pensive he saw Snape confining the curse to one hand on Dumbledore.

Secondly, Dumbledore is known to be a wizard of equal or of greater skill than Voldemort. Voldemort was capable of making a new hand for Pettigrew after he cut his off so that Voldemort could be revived.

Therefore logic dictates that Dumbledore should be capable of doing something similar, if I am right.

I have thought about it but I can't find any reason **why Dumbledore didn't remove his cursed hand and grow a fresh one in its place.**

Comment: Could you add more to this question? Where have you already looked for an answer?

Comment: Dumbledore repeatedly stated he's less powerful and skilled than Voldemort. Both to Minerva and Harry

Comment: @DVK - technically, that's not what he told McGonagall; he only stated that "Voldemort has powers that [Dumbledore] never will" (not exact wording); that doesn't mean that, of the powers they're both willing to use, that Dumbledore isn't sufficiently advanced that his overall power and skill would outrank Voldemort when you include Voldemort's Dark Arts. (And I don't remember when he said anything similar to Harry.)

Comment: I'd also suggest that Voldemort was prepared to do anything to get what he wanted. The growth of a new hand could well have involved things that Dumbledore was simply not prepared to do.

Comment: He might have tried Skywalker & Son Prosthetics...

Comment: There is a difference between physical hurts and magical hurts in terms of their ability to be treated/cured etc. in addition to the fact that the hand Pettigrew got isn't one I would ultimately want anyway - it was a deathly curse unto itself in the end.

Comment: Should we tag this question [star-wars] if everyone gets a prosthetic hand?

Comment: It would send his magical health insurance insurance rates through the roof.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Limbs or body parts that are cursed off by Dark Magic cannot grow back. Dumbledore's hand had been destroyed by Voldemort's powerful dark curse placed on the ring Horcrux. It may be that that rendered his hand too damaged to receive a new or prosthetic one:

> ‘Will George be OK?’
>   All Lupin’s frustration with Harry seemed to drain away at the
>   question.
>   ‘I think so, although there’s no chance of replacing his ear, not
>   when it’s been cursed off –’

and

> Harry saw a clean, gaping hole where George’s ear
>   had been.
>   ‘How is he?’
>   Mrs Weasley looked round and said, ‘I can’t make it grow
>   back, not when it’s been removed by Dark Magic. But it could
>   have been so much worse ... he’s alive.’
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - pages 64 and 66 - Bloomsbury - chapter 5, *The Fallen Warrior*</sub>

Perhaps Dumbledore might have been able to be fitted for a prosthetic hand, but the exact parameters for having prosthetic devices in Potterverse isn't known. Also, JKR herself says not all things can be fixed by magic. I don't know if self-injury would be considered Dark Magic if magic happened to be involved in someone removing their own limb. You'll note that Wormtail cut off his own hand using a plain old knife and didn't use magic to sacrifice his hand. Perhaps that is the reason why Voldemort was able to give Wormtail a magical prosthetic hand -- Wormtail's hand wasn't cursed by Dark Magic while Dumbledore's was.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I overlooked that fact.... o.o'

Comment: And Moody, who had wizards like Dumbledore as his friends, did not have a magical prosthetic leg for his lost one (leaving his nose) but only an ordinary (non-magical) wooden one.

Comment: The new question is: Couldn't Dumbledore simply live without a hand?

Comment: @EvilAngel: the curse was confined in the hand.  Chopping off the hand would release the curse.  (Well ... it *might* work that way for all we know.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - it might be worth adding your comment as an answer since it is objectively the most correct one. In the Deathly Hallows "The Prince's Tale" chapter - Snape says "..to contain [the curse] is all we can hope for; I have trapped the curse in one hand for the time being - '

Comment: @HarryJohnston So essentially the reason Dumbledore didn't cut off his hand is that if he cut it off he would have even less time to live? Makes sense when you think about it. I agree with NKCampbell, you should add this as an answer.